# Verifying validity of pointer in frama-c

Tags: c, frama-c

This is a really early frama-c question so sorry about that but I've been at it for a few hours and I can't get a really simple function to verify.  I know it's complaining about the function process and it was written purposefully poorly but I had hoped specifying that the memory had to be valid over the processing range would be enough to satisfy Alt-Ergo.  Where have I gone wrong?

The code:

```
#include <string.h>

extern int getStr(char *pStr, size_t len);

#define MAX_STR_LEN     25

/*@ requires \valid(a) && \valid(b);
@ ensures A: *a == \old(*b) ;
@ ensures B: *b == \old(*a) ;
@ assigns *a,*b ;
@*/
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
  int tmp;

  tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
  return;
}

/*  @ requires \valid(pStr+(0..1))
    @ assigns pStr[1];
*/
void process(char *pStr)
{
    pStr[1] = pStr[0];
}

void main()
{
    char string[MAX_STR_LEN];
    size_t size = getStr(string, MAX_STR_LEN);
    
    swap(&string[0], &string[1]);
    process(string);
}
```

Frama-c's response:

```
adam@blackbox:~/Programming/framatest$ frama-c -wp -wp-rte main.c 
[kernel] Parsing main.c (with preprocessing)
main.c:31:[kernel] warning: Neither code nor specification for function getStr, generating default assigns from the prototype
[rte] annotating function main
[rte] annotating function process
[rte] annotating function swap
[wp] 12 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_process_assert_rte_mem_access_2 : Unknown (Qed:0.62ms) (63ms)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_process_assert_rte_mem_access : Unknown (Qed:0.78ms) (62ms)
[wp] Proved goals:   10 / 12
    Qed:             7  (0.13ms-2ms-9ms)
    Alt-Ergo:        3  (4ms-6ms) (21) (unknown: 2)
```

Comment: It seems that you introduced some spaces between `/*` and `@` for the function process, thus these comments are seen as regular comments and not code annotations. Do you confirm that it is not a copy and paste error? If not, removing this spacing should solve the problem.

Comment: Be careful that since there's a space between the `/*` and the `@` the annotation is not seen as an ACSL contract, but as a simple comment (in fact, due to the missing `;` at the end of the requires, it is not syntactically correct as an ACSL annotation)

Comment: How interesting, the spaces were the problem  I was just trying to make it look cleaner but I understand syntactically why it has to be this way.  Thanks!